# How do you find and change an attribute within a list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

In my document, I have this:

```
<ul id='IDul_weekSelector' class='pagination pagination-sm>
   <li ><a href='#' status='enabled'>11</a></li>
   <li ><a href='#' status='enabled'>12</a></li>
   <li ><a href='#' status='enabled'>13</a></li>
   <li ><a href='#' status='enabled'>14</a></li>
   <li ><a href='#' status='enabled'>15</a></li>
   <li ><a href='#' status='enabled'>16</a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#' status='enabled'>17</a></li>
</ul>
```

On click I enter a function and read the week, $(this).text().  I want to change that clicked element's class to active which I can do.

Question is, how do I find the element that was shown as 'active' before the click and change it?  I can't have two concurrent 'active' list elements.

Thank you.

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.active').text()` should give you the other one you've pressed before (If you're catching click on `A` then it should be `$(this).parent().siblings('.active').text()`

Comment: Is that what you need? http://codepen.io/brunomonteiro3/pen/aNGvZG

Comment: Great.  Thanks all.  Got another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it using `$('#IDul_weekSelector li.active');` to return the li element with active class inside your ul.

You can use `$('#IDul_weekSelector li.active').removeClass('active');` to solve your problem.